# Magento Natural Images

Tags: magento

On a category page I have a slider with images from the the sub-categories thumbnails.  These images render completely very slow.  In checking I see that the natural size of these images are width 403px and height 430px.  When I made these images I made them width: 199px and height:300px.  I tried the below but it just effects the image size rendered and does not change the natural size.

```
.item .category-images{
width: 199px;
height:300px;
```

Images for slider are being pulled from thumbnail uploaded to category in admin.

Could someone tells me where I would edit the size of the natutal image?  I have looked in every file I can think of.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

To modify image sizes on a category page, navigate to **app\design\frontend\default\your_theme\your_template\catalog\product** folder.

Open **list.phtml**. Search for “resize”, then edit the section that looks like this:

```
 resize(100); ?>" width="100" height="100"
```

Make sure you do it in list and/or grid mode as required and refresh images cache.